# How to edit React-admin MuiTableCell or other Mui components?

Tags: material-ui, next.js, react-admin, mui-datatable

I'm building an Admin with React-Admin, and its documentation quite lacks clearance on how to edit the tables grid or other components. I need to edit the padding of the MuiTableCell. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve (I edit this with the Browser inspector)
[image]

I have a `theme.js` with the following, (this `theme.js`is located inside a `util):

```
function getTheme(name) {
  return createMuiTheme({
    ...themeConfig[name],
    ...themeConfig.common,
    overrides: {
      MuiTableCell: {
        root: {
          padding: "50px"
        } 
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is my current directory structure:

```
   |-- node_modules
   |-- public
   |-- src
     |-- components
     |-- pages
       |-- dashboard.js 
     |-- posts
     |-- util
       |-- theme.js
```

Any guidance on how can I edit my grids or dashboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `size="medium"` to your Datagrid:

```
const UserList = props => (
   <List {...props}>
      <Datagrid size="medium">
         <TextField source="first_name" />
         {/* ... */}
      </Datagrid>
   </List>
);
```